# How to remove dependent files produced with shake if the source file is deleted

Tags: shake-build-system

Using shake for a website generator, I encounter the already known problem of how to remove produce files when the source has been deleted. It seems to be difficult in general, but are there solutions for the specific case that a  `html` is produced for exactly one `markup` source?

In particular, if I know (from using `Twitch`) that a source file is deleted can I just go and delete the target? Does this cause any issues for shake?

Answer (score 0):

Deleting an unused target won't have any harmful effects on Shake. Even deleting a used target won't cause a problem - if Shake notices a target has disappeared it will simply rebuild it.

Even if you are not using Twitch there is a way to do this in Shake itself, as described at https://neilmitchell.blogspot.com/2015/04/cleaning-stale-files-with-shake.html. However, it's not that elegant or easy, so if Twitch is nice and easy I'd go with that.